# Python : create own method rather than relaying on "_mysql.escape_string(a)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I need a code to replace this..

```
import _mysql
a = "111"
a = _mysql.escape_string(a)
```

"a" is always gonna be a number between 1 and 1000+

and thus maybe there is a more secure way to "cleaning up" the "a" string in this example for mysql and etc..

rather than relying on

```
_mysql.escape_string()
```

function.

which we have no idea what it even does. or how it works. perhaps would be slower than something that we can invent given that all we are working is a number between 1 and 1000+

**RE-PHRASİNG THE QUESTİON:**

```
  How to ask python if the string is a maximum of 4 digit number"
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel & don't prematurely optimise

Comment: If it's a number, why not converting it to one?

Comment: i suppose my question should be.. "How to ask python if the string is a maximum of 4 character number"

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's a number:

```
>>> "1234".isdigit()
True
>>> "ABCD".isdigit()
False
```

Check its length:

```
>>> 1 <= len("1234") <= 4
True
>>> 1 <= len("12345") <= 4
False
```

---

`escape_string` won't clean your string. From the docs:

> "escape_string(s) -- quote any SQL-interpreted characters in string s.
>
> Use connection.escape_string(s), if you use it at all. _mysql.escape_string(s) cannot handle character sets. You are probably better off using connection.escape(o) instead, since
>   it will escape entire sequences as well as strings."